# Connect external php sheet to html sheet

Tags: php

I'm learning `php` now and I immediately got a doubt.

How do you link an `external php sheet` to an html sheet?

It is not possible to do the same thing as for example with a css sheet. Then it is inserted in the head of the html sheet `<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">`

Thank you

Comment: I've no idea what you mean by a "PHP sheet". It's unclear what the situation is and what you're trying to achieve. Are you asking how to include one PHP script file in another?

Comment: @ADyson, yes I'm asking how to include one PHP script file in another file like .html

Comment: You can't. You need to make both files into .php files. (one or both of then can still contain some HTML though.) And then use `include_once` or `require_once` in PHP to include one script inside the other.